# Result of the limit: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x + \sin(x)} - \sqrt{x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

From my calculations, the limit of 
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x + \sin(x)} - \sqrt{x}$

Is undefined due to $sin(x)$ being a periodic function, but someone told me it should be zero.

I was just wondering if someone could please confirm what the limit of this function is? Thanks
Corey :)

Comment: Did you try multiply by $\sqrt{ x+\sin(x) }+\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: Maybe $\sqrt{x+ \sin(x)}-\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{x\left(1+ \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)}-\sqrt{x}$. Now I believe bounded function $\sin(x)$ divided by $f(x) = x$, where $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ is 0. Therefore you are left with $\sqrt{x (1 + 0)} - \sqrt{x}$.

Comment: @quapka when you take limit, you must take it to all, so $\sqrt{\infty(1+0)}-\sqrt{\infty}$

Comment: @LuisFelipeVillavicencioLopez Sure, you are right.

Comment: When a function $f$ contains a periodic function you cannot automatically assume it does not exist. But when we do say "it does not exist because it is periodic", it is because the function appears to approach at least $2$ distinct unique limits. In your question, you have a limit in the $\infty - \infty$(indeterminate) form so you cannot say that it does not exist because it is perodic. Examples: $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \to 0$, $\lim_{x \to \infty}\sin(x) = DNE$

Comment: why is now answer accepted?

Answer (score 7):

$$\sqrt{x+\sin x}-\sqrt{x}=\frac{(x+\sin x)-(x)}{\sqrt{x+\sin x}+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{\sin x}{x}}+1}\to \frac{0}{\sqrt{1+0}+1}= 0$$

Answer (score 4):

Despite the periodicity of $\sin x$ the following inequalites hold: $$0\leftarrow\sqrt{x-1}-\sqrt{x}\le\sqrt{x+\sin x}-\sqrt{x}\le \sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}\to0,$$ therefore your limit is $0$ by the [squeeze theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

computing  $$\int_x^{x+\sin x} \frac{1}{2\sqrt t} dt $$ in two ways we find that $$\sqrt{x+\sin x} - \sqrt x =\frac1{2\sqrt{x+k\sin x}} \text{ for some } 0 < k < 1.$$ now letting $x \to \infty$ gives that $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt{x+\sin x} - x = 0. $$

Answer (score 1):

multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x+\sin(x)}+\sqrt{x}$

Answer (score 1):

as $x \to \infty$ we have (by rationalizing the numerator)
$$
\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x} \to 0
$$
substitute $x-1$ for $x$ to obtain
$$
\sqrt{x-1} - \sqrt{x} \to 0
$$
now use:
$$
\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x} \ge \sqrt{x+\sin x} - \sqrt{x} \ge  \sqrt{x-1} - \sqrt{x} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to be able to do this
$$\sqrt{x+\sin x}-\sqrt{x}= \sqrt{x+\sin x -x}=\sqrt{\sin x}=\dots$$
But this just isn't valid. It would be nice to be able to just remove the radical signs. Can you think of a way to do this ? (**hint**: think difference of squares)

Answer (score 0):

or use the binomial theorem
$$
\sqrt{x+\sin x}-\sqrt{x} = \sqrt{x} \left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{\sin x}
{x}}-1\right) \\
= \sqrt{x}\left( \frac{\sin x}x + O(\frac1{x^2}) \right) \to 0
$$

Answer (score -3):

I think the limit is $0$, since $sin(x)$ is bounded: At best, it is $1$ or $-1$, but if $x \rightarrow \infty$, a bounded number will look like a const; it won't influence the limit, so basically you have $\sqrt{x}- \sqrt{x}= 0$

Comment: This doesn't work in general. Compare to $(x+\sin(x))^2-x^2$ or even $(x+\sin(x))-x$

Comment: But in this case, it works.

Comment: What is a result worth if the proof is wrong?

Comment: try improving your arguments in math